# Getting an image's 'real' width and height in IE

Tags: javascript, html, image, internet-explorer, shadowbox

I'm currently building a site and using the Shadowbox JS plugin to display images.

Because we serve up images via a JSP (rather than linking directly to image files), Shadowbox seems unable to dynamically determine their width and height and so just opens the images in an overlay of ~the screen size.

It's possible to manually pass in widths and heights to the shadowbox plugin using 'rel', so I've got around the problem for FF/Chrome/Safari using the following code:

```
$('#pic1img').attr("src")).load(function() {
            picWidth    = this.width;
            picHeight   = this.height;
    });

 $(window).load(
            function() {
                var w = $("#pic1img").width();
                var h = $("#pic1img").height();
                if( picWidth < w ){ picWidth = w; }
                if( picHeight < h ){ picHeight = h; }
                $('#pic1').attr('rel', 'shadowbox[pics];height=' + picHeight + ';width=' + picWidth);
            }
 );
```

But I can't find any way to do the same in IE.

Comment: What specifically happens in IE? Are you looking for the naturalWidth and naturalHeight properties?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code actually worked once I began loading the thumbnails at full size and then setting their width and height after load.

The issue was that I was setting a surrounding div to

```
display: none
```

until the images were loaded and IE can't work out the sizes of hidden images.

Resolved this by setting

```
visibility: hidden
```

instead.

Comment: More on this topic: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2011/03/14/internet-explorer-hidden-images-styled-with-display-none-always-have-zero-0-height.aspx

Comment: In addition to this, you can use `position: absolute` to prevent the hidden images from taking up space on the screen (in most situations).